# How to fix the CSS issue in the interactive jquery category filter

Tags: jquery, html

I created an interactive jquery category filter but if I select any option, the search result page shows me contents with gaps between them. Like one content has a lot of distance between it and the next content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".catagory_buttton").click(function() {
    var catagory = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(catagory);
    if (catagory == 'girl') {
      $('.human_class').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.' + catagory).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
    if (catagory == 'boy') {
      $('.human_class').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.' + catagory).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.catagory_container {
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.catagory_buttton {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.catagory_buttton:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.4 ease.in.out;
}

.human_class {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="catagory_container">
    <p class="catagory_buttton" id="girl">Girl</p>
    <p class="catagory_buttton" id="boy">Boys</p>
  </div>
  <div class=".containerItem">
    <p class="human_class boy"><span>nawaz</span></p>
    <br>
    <p class="human_class girl"><span>Aysha</span></p>
    <br>
    <p class="human_class girl"><span>fatime</span></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get rid of those dirty `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, giving a   `clear:both` to `.human_class` and removing `<br>` tag and changing `.hide` implementation as

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

will solve the issue you can check it in below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".catagory_buttton").click(function() {
    var catagory = $(this).attr('id');
    //alert(catagory);
    if (catagory == 'girl') {
      $('.human_class').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.' + catagory).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
    if (catagory == 'boy') {
      $('.human_class').addClass('hide');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.' + catagory).removeClass('hide');
      }, 300);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.catagory_container {
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.catagory_buttton {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
}

.catagory_buttton:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin:0;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}

.human_class {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear:both
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="catagory_container">
    <p class="catagory_buttton" id="girl">Girl</p>
    <p class="catagory_buttton" id="boy">Boys</p>
  </div>
  <div class=".containerItem">
    <p class="human_class boy"><span>nawaz</span></p>
    <p class="human_class girl"><span>Aysha</span></p>
    <p class="human_class girl"><span>fatime</span></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is working it but on my chrome browser it not working.

Comment: Can you pls check for any css or script overrides